# inputting image links into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, image, hyperlink

So I've hit a bit of a snag. I'm working on a form that uploads an image file to an ftp and creates an entry into mysql with the link to the image as well as a column that would be used to organize and order the images.

I'm getting the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'order) VALUES( '', '../tattoo/1.jpg', '6')' at line 1

I have tried placing '' around the values and not and I still get the same message. I'm sure the solution is simple and I'm just tired and have been staring at it too long. here is the code

```
    <?php
   // Configuration - Your Options
      $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png'); // These will be the types     of file that will pass the validation.
      $max_filesize = 524288; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 0.5MB).
      $upload_path = '../tattoo/'; // The place the files will be uploaded to.

   $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
   $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.

   // Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
   if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
      die('The file you attempted to upload is not the proper format, please submit a .jpg, .gif, .bmp, or .png');

   // Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
   if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
      die('The file you attempted to upload is too large. Max file size is 0.5MB');

   // Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
   if(!is_writable($upload_path))
      die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

   // Upload the file to your specified path.
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
         echo 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <a href="' . $upload_path . $filename . '" title="Your File">here</a><p>'; // It worked.
      else
         echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.'; // It failed :(.

// Add picture listing to mysql

    //Include database connection details
    include('config.php');

    //Connect to mysql server
    $mysql = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$mysql) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("sonyaopal", $mysql) or die( "Unable to select database" .  mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query ( "SELECT count(*) from tattoos" );

$location = '' . $upload_path . $filename . '';
$order = $result+1; 

    $insListing_sql = "INSERT INTO tattoos (id, location, order) VALUES('', 
            '".mysql_real_escape_string("$location")."',
            '".mysql_real_escape_string("$order")."')"; 
    $insListing_res = mysql_query($insListing_sql, $mysql)
            or die(mysql_error($mysql));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the below code and try it:

```
<?php

//getting the filename of the image file.
$filename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];

//directory name to be stored.
$path = "data/mydata";

//uploading the image file with the image file name into the directory.
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],$path."/".$filename) {

//if the image is stored success into the directory then we are going to store into database.

//the real path with the filename.

$mysql_path = $path."/".$filename;

//sql query to be executed.
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tablename`(`filename`,`path`) VALUES ('$filename','$mysql_path')";

//executing the query.
if(mysql_query($sql)) {
echo 'path inserted into database';
}
else {
echo 'path not inserted into database';
}
}
else {
echo 'file not uploaded';
}
?>
```

The error is in your INSERT QUERY did you run the Query manually and checked..